# how to fix my hp envy m6 that stopped working?

Tags: windows-8, hp-envy

I was working on my HP Envy m6 and it tripped off. When I press the power button, the charging point LED light blinks and the system does not power up.

When I remove the battery and plug into the power adapter directly, the same thing happens.

How can I fix this problem? I can't even factor what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Superuser!

Please try a hard reset:

Unplug power cord

Remove battery

**Hold power button in for 15-20 seconds.**

Attach only power cord for first startup attempt

The step in bold can be very important in some cases, so its worth a try.

Comment: You are such a life saver. Imagine having a Ruby Application to submit today and my system did that?
After trying your suggestion, it came on with a direct power plug. Can you explain exactly what happened from my posted problem and why your answer being a fix?
I like to thank you once again.

Comment: Glad I could help! Given the complexity of the electrical circuits inside a laptop, residual power remains in the system even when the system has been turned off. Holding down the power button forces that residual energy to drain so *everything* turns off fully - and responds to the power button again

Comment: Wow. Thank you. You are such a Teacher as well. Thanks